# inline assembly jump to labels

Tags: c++, c, assembly, inline-assembly

I have problems to jump to an label.

My Code:

```
    asm{
keypress: 
    ...
    cmp ax,0000
    jz keypress
}
```

Borland says: Undefined Label "keypress"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the label to outside of the asm block (i.e., just above the "asm{" line).  This is per this [link](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=972872) and this [link](http://computer-programming-forum.com/45-asm/352fc0aba350241b.htm).

Also note that evidently you may not be able to jump to a forward label (per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209198/borland-x86-inlined-assembler-get-a-labels-address)), but that's of course not your problem in this example.